# npm install error Invalid Package: expected taffydb but found taffydb-jsdoc

Tags: npm-install

Running npm install and failed with error the following is from npm-debug.log file The same commands works yesterday. There's no change in package.json file.

```
15065 info install gulp-jsdoc@0.1.5
15066 info postinstall gulp-jsdoc@0.1.5
15067 verbose unlock done using /home/centos/.npm/_locks/gulp-jsdoc-a48e57f10f1c6755.lock for /data/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/gulp-jsdoc
15068 verbose stack Error: Invalid Package: expected taffydb but found taffydb-jsdoc
15068 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-local-tarball.js:127:21
15068 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:356:5
15068 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:320:45)
15068 verbose stack     at final (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:354:3)
15068 verbose stack     at then (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:124:5)
15068 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:243:12
15068 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
15068 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:380:3)
15069 verbose cwd /data/jenkins/workspace/
15070 error Linux 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
15071 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
15072 error node v4.4.5
15073 error npm  v2.15.5
15074 error Invalid Package: expected taffydb but found taffydb-jsdoc
15075 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
15075 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
15076 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
15077 verbose unbuild node_modules/jsdoc
15078 info preuninstall jsdoc@3.3.0-alpha5
15079 info uninstall jsdoc@3.3.0-alpha5
```

Thanks

G.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that this latest commit in the taffydb-jsdoc fork has broken it:
https://github.com/hegemonic/taffydb/commit/507d2d75fa16e1386f6d50abee1894b264d4458b
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/taffydb-jsdoc)

(Description updated)
The package has been renamed from taffydb to taffydb-jsdoc, so npm is finding a conflict between the expected and the declared package names. In our case and the OP's, hegemonic's fork of taffydb is being referenced by jsdoc, which is a node module required by gulp-jsdoc:
https://github.com/jsBoot/gulp-jsdoc/blob/v0.1.4/package.json#L39
https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/blob/v3.3.0-alpha5/package.json#L26

EDIT: The author of this fork has contacted me to say the issue has been resolved, as shown in this new commit (package name reverted):
https://github.com/hegemonic/taffydb/commit/e41b5e179e197bb85c5fb887b707672b1e5ca079

I can confirm that our npm install(s) are now working again.